# Is it possible to have a page-relative child div which exists inside a fixed parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure this is even possible and the only reason I'm asking is because I'm dealing with an existing site that I need to "lightly" modify. So yes, I understand this is bad practice, but I wanted to know if it was at least possible.

If I have a parent DIV with `position: fixed;` and `top: 0;`, is it possible to have a child within that DIV which flows relative to the page? (Basically, this child DIV needs to scroll with the page while the parent and its remaining content stays fixed).

I've tried to set the child DIV to every `position:` possible, but I'm not able to let this child escape its parent.

Current [code example](https://codepen.io/Rogue75/pen/jObQKyJ).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

* {
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%; 
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<DIV class="parent">

  <DIV class="child1">
    child1 should stay at top during scroll
  </DIV>
  
  <DIV class="child2">
    child2 should scroll with page (begin to dissappear once the page is scrolled down). What (if anything) can I apply to this child to get this behavior?
  </DIV>
  
</DIV>
```

Preferably this would be done with only HTML & CSS, but I'm open to hearing alternative methods.

Comment: Please post your code to the question, and not a codepen link. If you can modify the HTML, why would you keep the child in a fixed parent?

Comment: why the parent need to be fixed to start with?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the parent div is a fixed header

Comment: @disinfor the child exists inside a fixed header. Whatever is in the header exists on all webpages (the site is made in www.wocode.com site builder). I want this child repeated on every page so that's why it's in the fixed header, but I want it to disappear on scroll.

Comment: So you have a header template? Again, it seems like you could move the child `div` out of that containing `fixed div` element. What does the template builder code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Code change needed for both HTML and CSS. Please run the code snippet and check the desire behavior.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

* {
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="parent">
  <DIV class="child1">
    child1 should stay at top during scroll
  </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="child2">
  child2 should scroll with page (begin to dissappear once the page is scrolled down). What (if anything) can I apply to this child to get this behavior?
</DIV>
```